Sending Event Viewer logs to Powerbi with nxlog
I am creating a powerbi dashboard that gets logs from a csv created by nxlog config. This config gets all the logs from event viewer and categorizes them. I am having trouble creating a proper config that would include everything I would need for log dashboard. I have a basic config going but would like to add headers and everything else I need.
This is what I have currently:
`<Input eventlog>
  Module im_msvistalog
</Input>

<Output out_csv>
Module om_file
File "C:\\Logs\\all_eventlogs.csv"
<Exec>

    # Format fields and construct CSV line
    $EventTime = strftime($EventTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");     # Format timestamp
    $Message = replace($Message, "\n", " ");                    # Remove line breaks in message

     $csv_line = '"' + $EventTime + '","' + $UserID + '","' + $SourceName + '","' + $EventID +         '","' + $Severity + '","' + $Message + '"';
    log_info($csv_line);    # Log CSV line to verify format in nxlog.log
    # Output the constructed CSV line
    $raw_event = $csv_line;
  </Exec>
 </Output>

 <Route 1>
 Path eventlog => out_csv
 </Route>`

I want it to output a csv with proper headers and everything else I may need to monitor logs.
